# Tekton dashboard deployment error- Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "config/service.yaml"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am trying to practice the steps in my local using minikube. From the teokton-dashboard in my local I am able to import the resource using git url. I followed all the steps but when creating pipeline runs I am getting error as Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "config/service.yaml". I tried using default namespace as well as tekton-pipeline namespace. I used tekton-dashboard as serviceAccount.

```
[![Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "myapp", Namespace: "tekton-pipelines"
from server for: "config/deployment.yaml": deployments.apps "myapp" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:tekton-pipelines:tekton-dashboard" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "tekton-pipelines"
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "config/service.yaml": services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:tekton-pipelines:tekton-dashboard" cannot create resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "tekton-pipelines"][1]][1]
```

Attaching screenshots for reference

[image: Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration]

Comment: it's due to service account you are using don't have permission to use the deployment resource form kubernets.

Comment: https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/1830